# Cannot overload boolean operators in F#

Tags: f#, operator-overloading, boolean

F# does allow overloading of arithmetic operators like +, but seems to disallow this for boolean operators like ||. The following code generates a warning and two errors:

```
type MyBool =
    val Value : bool
    new(value) = { Value = value }
    static member (||) (v1: MyBool, v2 : MyBool) =
        new MyBool(v1.Value || v2.Value)
let b1 = new MyBool(true)
let b2 = new MyBool(false)
let b3 = b1 || b2
```

Warning (on the static member (||) definition): The name '(||)' should not be used as a member name. If defining a static member for use from other CLI languages then use the name 'op_BooleanOr' instead.

Error (on b1 and b2 in the 'let b3' statement): This expression was expected to have type bool but here has type MyBool

If I use op_BooleanOr instead of (||) the warning disappears, but the errors remain.

When I do exactly the same thing for the + operator in a MyInt type there are no warnings or errors. So, why do these warnings/errors appear when I try to overload || or &&?

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid that the F# compiler doesn't have any treatment of logical operators that would allow you to override them (as C# does). As far as I can tell, `x && y` is compiled simply as `if x then y else false`, so `x` has to be boolean. I didn't check whether the F# compiler supports this behavior for types declared in C#, but I don't think it does.

As far as I know, the best way to emulate short-circuiting behvaior for your own operator is to use the `lazy` keyword to create lazy values. Then you can write something like:

```
let foo b = 
  printfn "foo %b" b
  MyBool(b)

lazy foo true &&! lazy foo false    // Calls 'foo' for both branches
lazy foo false &&! lazy foo false   // Calls 'foo' only for the first one
```

The two operators can be defined using static member constraints, so they should (in principle) work for any types that implement the operators required by C#.

```
let inline (&&!) (x:Lazy<_>) (y:Lazy<_>) = 
  if (^T: (static member op_False : ^T -> bool) x.Value)
    then x.Value else x.Value &&& y.Value

let inline (||!) (x:Lazy<_>) (y:Lazy<_>) = 
  if (^T: (static member op_False : ^T -> bool) x.Value) 
    then x.Value else x.Value ||| y.Value
```

Then you can define your `MyBool` types with all the required operators (as a side note, it should be usable in the natural way from C# if you define it like this):

```
type MyBool(b) =
  member x.Value = b
  static member (|||) (v1: MyBool, v2 : MyBool) = 
    MyBool(v1.Value || v2.Value) 
  static member (&&&) (v1: MyBool, v2 : MyBool) = 
    MyBool(v1.Value && v2.Value) 
  static member op_True (v: MyBool) = v.Value
  static member op_False (v: MyBool) = not v.Value
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 5):

`&&` and `||` differ from other operators in that they're short-circuiting and can thus not be implemented simply as methods. Because of this .net defines [special rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691312%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) you need to follow to enable the usage of `&&` and `||` with your own types.

In short: you need to define `operator true` and `operator false` as well.

Comment: Is there a way to implement `operator true` and `operator false` in F#? I cannot find it.

Comment: @Halbe: I don't know actually. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It clarifies the reasons for the warning and errors in any case!